# How do add an apitoken as part of a custom VSTS service endpoint datasource?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm am trying to implement a VSTS extension which adds a new service endpoint. Crucially, the authentication method for this service includes the API as part of the querystring.

I am using the `"type": "ms.vss-endpoint.endpoint-auth-scheme-token"` for `AuthenticationScheme`.

I've defined the `dataSources` like so:

```
"dataSources": [
    {
        "name": "TestConnection",
        "endpointUrl": "{{endpoint.url}}projects?token={{endpoint.apitoken}}"
    }
]
```

However, in performing a test to `Verify Connection`:

> Failed to query service endpoint api: https://myserver.com/projects?token=.

`endpoint.apitoken` is always blank.

Is there a placeholder/replacement value that can be used to get access to this value or another way of achieving the same end result?

I've tried using different authentication schemes (such as '`none`') and included a `inputDescriptor` to capture my `apitoken`, but I have the same result. There doesn't seem to be a way to reference these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not supported. This article may benefit you: [Service endpoint authentication schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/auth-schemes?view=vsts)

Comment: I managed to get the following working. Am using the `auth scheme` of `none`. Have then put an `inputDescriptors` on the parent `properties` element (ie, not on the `authenticationSchemes`. `dataSources` are now able to read these values, however they do not appear to be hidden in log output if the value is echo'd out even with `isConfidential` set.

Comment: I don't think the property can kept confidential.